# Cite fails after `\tableofcontents` in `svjour3.cls` when `todonotes` is loaded

Tags: table-of-contents, errors, citing, todonotes, sv-classes

When using the Springer class `svjour3` (can be obtained [here](https://www.springer.com/gp/livingreviews/latex-templates)), I stumbled upon a problem with `\cite`. Look at the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{svjour3}

\usepackage{todonotes}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{test1}
% \cite{test2}
\tableofcontents
\cite{test1}
\cite{test2}
\end{document}
```

You can use two arbitrary bib entries with keys `test1` and `test2` in `references.bib` for this.

When you compile this, both cites of `test1` work, but the cite to `test2` does not work. Anything of the following fixes the issue:

- comment out the `todonotes` package,
- comment out the `\tableofcontents`, or
- use the `article` class instead of `svjour3`.

I checked the definition of `\tableofcontents` in `svjour3`, which is

```
\newcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \section*{\contentsname}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\begingroup\protect\small}%
    \AtEndDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}}%
    }
```

Indeed, using `article` with this definition of `\tableofcontents` also fails. Any insights on what's happening here? Is this expected behavior or a bug in `svjour3`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! When you say 'the cite to `test2` does not work', what do you mean exactly? Do you get an error? A warning? No output? A question mark as output? Something in the log file?

Comment: The fact that you are using `biblatex` might also be very relevant here, plus you are never printing the bibliography.

Comment: @Marijn: Instead of the citation being shown like `[2]` I get the cite key in the square brackets (i.e., `[test2]`).

Comment: As I see it `biblatex` is not compatible with `svjou3`, it seems to mess with some stuff about the table of contents such that the `\AtEndDocument` line is never executed. You get a warning like this in the log: `### semi simple group (level 1) entered at line 22 (\begingroup)`, and the missing `\endgroup` can be verified by looking in the `.toc` file

Comment: @daleif: Indeed, without `biblatex` it seems to work. But with `biblatex` it does not work, even if I print the bibliography at the end (via `\printbibliography`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`biblatex` seems to be injecting stuff into the toc. One can wonder why Springer chose this definition

```
\newcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \section*{\contentsname}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\begingroup\protect\small}%
    \AtEndDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}}%
    }
```

especially adding `\begingroup\small` and `\endgroup` into the toc file.

When `biblatex` is used we can see that the `\endgroup` is missing from the `.toc` file. So essentially all the `\cite` commands after `\tableofcontents` run like

```
\begingroup
\cite{test1} etc
```

with no `\endgroup`, I'm not sure why this makes `biblatex`'s `\cite` not write its information to the `.aux`.

Why didn't Springer just use

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
  \section*{\contentsname}%
  \begingroup
    \small
    \@starttoc{toc}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

instead of injecting this information into the `.toc`, where it (IMO) does not belong. The above redefinition works just fine with `biblatex`

Though, you might want to check with Springer on whether they do support `biblatex` in their production. Not all publishers do.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the fix!