# Incompatibility: biblatex / tableofcontents / tikz / springer class?

Tags: tikz-pgf, biblatex, table-of-contents, sv-classes

I am completely stumped by the following MWE, on which any run of pdflatex except the very first run results in a citation-free .bcf file, whereupon biber complains:

`WARN - The file 'mwe.bcf' does not contain any citations!`

The problem disappears if I do *either one* of the following:

1. comment out \tableofcontents;
2. comment out \usepackage{tikz};
3. switch the documentclass from [svjour3](//tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280889/springer-svjour3) (downloaded [here](//www.springer.com/journal/10711/submission-guidelines)) to amsart.

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}
% \documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Knuth:2014,
    Author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    Howpublished = {\url{http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2213858}},
    Title = {Twenty Questions for Donald Knuth},
    Year = {2014}}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,backref=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents 

\section{One}
\cite{Knuth:2014}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

If debugging(?) the Springer classes is (understandably) deemed not tex.se’s job then I’d still appreciate a pointer on where else to ask.

Comment: Welcome! I had a quick look at the class (but am not brave enough to install it). Does adding `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` after `\usepackage{tikz}` help?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks for looking! Unfortunately, no change. (No need to install the class — it should work by just putting their svjour3.cls, 48 KB, and maybe svglov3.clo, 4 KB, in the same dir as my MWE.)

Comment: Ooh! It seems to be the same problem (with same solution) as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/490777/cite-fails-after-tableofconents-in-svjour3-cls-when-todonotes-is-loaded Can someone please close this as duplicate, and maybe advise if there is any chance Springer might be goaded into fixing it?

Comment: You can always send an email to Springer and tell them about this issue, whether they'll see the need to act is another thing. (Unfortunately, the template appears to have no contact information, so you'll have to find out whom to contact via some other ways.) Note that both `usrguid3.pdf` and `template.tex` either explicitly or implicitly say that you should be using BibTeX (with `\bibliographystyle`) or manual `thebibliography`. That would mean that you can not use `biblatex`. Indeed, `biblatex` requires a different workflow that publishers may not be inclined to adapt to. ...

Comment: ... Unless you have been explicitly asked by journal/publishing editors/staff to use `biblatex` (or have requested and been granted permission to do so), I strongly recommend not using `biblatex` for submissions to journals/publishers using this class (it's similar for other publishers and their classes as well).

Comment: @moewe It’s a little bit sad how little adoption biblatex achieved. To the extent I’m contemplating going back to writing .bst style files in their crazy reverse polish syntax...